# Vertical surface would lose heat faster by convection than a horizontal surface?

Tags: thermodynamics, newtonian-gravity, convection

Is the heat coeff affected by gravity?

Vertical surface would lose heat faster by convection than a horizontal surface?

Comment: Edited. Sorry..

Comment: Gravity is what causes natural convection, so, yes, the heat transfer coefficient is, of course, affected by gravity.

Comment: Thanks chester, what about the vertical and horizontal question?

Comment: You can use the correlations in Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot to evaluate this.  My inclination would be to say that vertical has a higher heat transfer coefficient.

Comment: -1. No reasearch effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer to the orientation question: It depends on many factors, but a vertical surface generally transfers heat faster.**

Only one type of heat transfer coefficient is strongly affected by gravity: **the [convection coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection) for [natural convection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection)**; the reason is that warmer air is less dense than cooler air. Natural convection describes hot air billowing upward or past above a hot object, for example, or cool air sinking past a cold object.

(In contrast, forced convection—air being forcefully blown past an object—isn't strongly affected by gravity. Nor are conduction or radiation.)

Natural convection is challenging to model from first principles because it involves a fluid moving at some particular speed, directly past an object of arbitrary roughness and particular temperature, with a varying boundary layer thickness and circulation profile. The large number of variables and the resulting uncertainty means that natural convection coefficients often take the form of empirical fits to experiments or simulations rather than theory-derived formulas.

The convection coefficient $h$ modulates the heat flow $Q$ through a cross-sectional area $A$ resulting from a difference in temperature $\Delta T$ (i.e., the temperature difference between the surface and the ambient environment):

$$Q=hA\Delta T\tag{1}$$

It's common to express the convection coefficient as a function of the so-called [Nusselt number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nusselt_number) $\mathrm{Nu}$, the [thermal conductivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conductivity) of the fluid (here, air) $k$, and a characteristic length $L^*$, e.g., the length of the plate in the direction of flow or the area of the surface divided by its perimeter:

$$h=\mathrm{Nu}\times\frac{k}{L^*}\tag{2}$$

In addition, certain dimensionless numbers demarcate ranges over which certain behaviors hold. These include the [Prandtl number $\mathrm{Pr}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prandtl_number), [Grashof number $\mathrm{Gr}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grashof_number), [Reynolds number $\mathrm{Re}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number), and [Rayleigh number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_number) $\mathrm{Ra}=\mathrm{Pr}\times\mathrm{Gr}$.

At the end of it all, you might encounter an empirical formula such as

$$\mathrm{Nu}=0.68+\frac{0.67\mathrm{Re}^{1/4}}{[1+(0.492/\mathrm{Pr})^{9/16}]^{4/9}}\tag{3}$$

which is applicable for a vertical plate with height $L=L^*$ when the Rayleigh number satisfies $0.1<\mathrm{Ra}<10^9$ and the material properties are taken at temperature $(T+T_\infty)/2$, except for the thermal expansion coefficient (which appears in the Grashof number), which is taken at the ambient temperature $T_\infty$.

**With this information in mind, we can address your question** by looking at the Nusselt number $\mathrm{Nu}$ as a function of inclination angle. You can find one summary in [Section 7.7 here](https://www.researchgate.net/file.PostFileLoader.html?id=579747fc3d7f4b9edf22872b&assetKey=AS%3A388060144521217%401469532156767) from Holman's *Heat Transfer*. You can also find charts of the Nusselt number for horizontal and vertical flat plates on p. 14 [here](https://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/SimRoof/Convection/Convection.pdf). Note that the bottom chart has log axes. For a given Rayleigh number, the Nusselt numbers are similar. In fact, the dependence on inclination angle scales as $(cos\,\theta)^{1/4}$ in an additive factor, where $\theta=0^\circ$ describes a vertical surface. The exact details depend on whether the bottom or top of the surface is being heated.

**We conclude that the heat transfer from a vertical plate is somewhat higher than that from a horizontal plate, but generally not more than an order of magnitude larger, for example.** (One exception is a very large heated surface directed straight down, which would lose essentially no energy through natural convection. A slight tilt could be expected to increase the heat transfer rate substantially.) Expect the actual results to vary depending on the roughness of the surface, its exact temperature variation, and the orientation and spacing of the surrounding objects, among other variables.